# OutOfMemoryError on Java on macOS

Tags: java, memory, server, out-of-memory

I am developing a Java server application which used to run fine on a PC running Debian. Recently, I moved it in production on a MacMini with macOS High Sierra. Everything seemed to be working fine for weeks until recently, I got random OutOfMemoryErrors almost once a day. When it happens, the server app seems to stop responding to most request and I need to kill it and start it again.

When it happens, on the Activity Monitor, my server app is using about about 2GB or 4GB, which is well below the limit I set for the app (which is -Xmx8G).

I don't know where should I look to fix this issue and I need your insight.

Some notes: The MacMini has 16GB. The server is running headlessly on Java SDK 1.8. It is launch under a GNU screen. The app is using a lot of HashMaps and using Lucene with a FSDirectory to index documents and manage queries.

**EDIT**: Here's an example of the error:

```
Exception in thread "NRT Reopen Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.merge(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:553)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:2247)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:511)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(StandardDirectoryReader.java:293)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:268)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:258)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:140)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:156)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.doMaybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:176)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefreshBlocking(ReferenceManager.java:253)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ControlledRealTimeReopenThread.run(ControlledRealTimeReopenThread.java:226)
```

Comment: Most likely it's not running out of heap as you suggest, there are many reasons you can get an OutOfMemoryError including a lack of perm gen/metaspace, unable to create a new thread. I suggest you include the error message with the OOME.

Comment: Thanks a lot! These errors are missing from my logs files. I think it was something like "Unable to create new native thread". But as soon as I get another error, I'll update this post with more details.

Comment: That means you have reached the limit of how many threads you are allowed to create.

Comment: It was indeed "unable to create new native thread " errors, thank you. I found a that there was a thread pooling with a default size of 10,000 threads, maybe it's more than we need. I reduced it to 1,000 and we'll see what happens.

Comment: For future reference, there are various tools which give you a visual indication of how your JVM is using resources. If someone is paying for this work, it might be worth it to license one of those tools.

Comment: @BéatriceCassistat if the tasks in a pool are CPU bound you might find that having more threads than you have processes is actually slower.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: ITYM more threads than CPUs aka processORs, not processes

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 correct *processors